Getting "The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold" despite amount of filtered data is less then 5000
I am using a following API link to get a list of old files from SharePoint site:
https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Documents')/items?$filter=Modified le '2017-12-06T18:30:00Z' 

But getting "The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold" despite the fact that amount of filtered files is less then 5000 items (getting that message regardless of how old files looked for) , but amount of all files might be more than 5000 .
Does the call get all the files first and then filter it?
Any other api/way to quickly get list of very old files from sp site?
Thanks

Try adding indexing on columns you are using for sorting or filtering (like Modified column). Let me know if it works for you.

Not really an option - we have few thousands sites, wouldnt do it for all of them

Actually, I just checked one site I used for testing, and "Modified" column is indexed
